# Using Oracle, suddenly receiving ORA-12154 TNS: could not resolve message

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I was connecting to a Oracle database perfectly using PL/SQL Developer. I tried to access the DB from my java code. After that I received this error "ORA-12154 TNS: could not resolve" from PL/SQL Developer; I am still able to access database and query on it from my code.

I have read suggested solutions for this error but since I am using a thin client with limited privilege on both Windows and a database server (I can only query on it!!), I was not able to use them.

I appreciate any suggestion for solving this problem.

And also I am very curious about the reason for this issue since everything was fine before I ran my code; which is as simple as connecting to a database and querying one view which I had privileges to!!! 
And please note that other users on other thin clients are not able to connect with PL/SQL Developer either.
My code is as follows:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here

   Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");
    FileHandler fh;
    fh = new FileHandler("C:/Users/batam/Documents/MyLogFile.log");
    logger.addHandler(fh);
    SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
    fh.setFormatter(formatter);

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@capmtr10:1521/FINDATA1", "bamat",
                "fg_3002");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

              e.printStackTrace();

        return;

    }

    if (connection != null) {

        try {
            String sql = "select a.userid, a.Description from USER_FINANCE a where a.userid = 'batam'";

            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {

                String id = rs.getString("userid");
                String name = rs.getString("Description");

                logger.info("Selecteds are : " + id + " : " + name);
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.info("SQLException : " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(IFS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                logger.info("Close Exception : " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        logger.info("Failed to make connection!");
    }

}
```

I have retrieved the Server host name and service name from PL/SQL developer on my thin client using system_context function while it was still connecting without this error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us the code which caused the exception.

Comment: PL/SQL is not a tool to access Oracle. What's the real name of the tool you have used? PL/SQL Developer? SQLplus? SQL Developer? Toad?

Comment: And what connection string are you using in Java? And what connection settings did you specify in the other tool?

Comment: Dears I have added answer to your questions to my question's main body

Comment: PL/SQL Developer use to have a bug because of the installation folder. If you install it under program files (x86) folder it won't resolve the TNS listener. Don't know if they fixed it. It was pretty annoying. Worth to check

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the oracle client tools? If so, tnsping YOUR_SID on cmd would give you the status of your connection to the database.